# WebView underneath Andengine

Tags: layout, view, webview, andengine

I'm trying to put a joypad made with AndEngine on a WebView that will be the view of an ipCamera. How can I do? I've searched a lot about that, but still haven't found the solution. Thank you all very much

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what version of AndEngine you are using.

If you are using GLES2 (same technique may work for the GLES1 branch but I have not verified that), look at the AndEngine TextBreakExample.

That example shows how to use the org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView in combination with another layout like a LinearLayout. The "other layout" can contain anything - this example uses an EditText, but you should be able to use a WebView using the same technique.

Be sure and check the res/layout/textbreakexample.xml file. Also note these extra methods in the TextBreakExample.java file

```
@Override
protected int getLayoutID() {
    return R.layout.textbreakexample;
}

@Override
protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() {
    return R.id.textbreakexample_rendersurfaceview;
}
```

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/TextBreakExample.java

https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/res/layout/textbreakexample.xml

Also might check out this layout file
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/res/layout/xmllayoutexample.xml

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think i've already tryed something like that, but i must have done it wrongly. I can't find the example you mentioned, please can you link me that and the .xml file?

Comment: I added the links to my original answer - you should bookmark that page for Nicholas on github as it's the master source for AndEngine

Comment: Thanks.I haven't solve the problem.The example put the Textview on the top, but i need to put it under.I've tryed a lot of solutions,but the background of the andengine view is never transparent or set with my layout.This is my .java 
`@Override
protected int getLayoutID() {
return R.layout.interfacciarobotactivity;
}
@Override
protected int getRenderSurfaceViewID() {
return R.id.webview_rendersurfaceview;
}
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {
super.onSetContentView();
baseIntWV=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.baseIntWV);
baseIntWV.loadUrl("..");
}`
Start thinking that it's impossible...

Comment: personally, I'd use a RelativeLayout in the xml - the z-index is stacked such that the bottom item in the layout is on top. In your xml file put the AndEngine view last and see if that helps.